# Excluding certain records from a Django queryset as long as those records are not the first or last X records

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a Django recordset (mysource) holding temperature reading for each day (for_date). When the last 40 days readings are available for me, for example, I want to display only 20 days on a graph. To accomplish this, I do the following:

```
for day_num in range (1, 32):
   if day_num % 2 == 1: # remove every 2nd day
      mysource = mysource.exclude(for_date__day=day_num)
```

...in order to remove every second reading from the queryset. It works great, but now I want to display the most recent reading and the least recent reading and make sure I dont exclude those from the queryset. Is there any easy/quick way to specify an exclude for records from a Django queryset as long as those records are not located at neither the beginning X records of the queryset nor the end X records of the queryset so I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use queries to get the PKs of the records you want to exclude, then exclude them in your primary query (`.exclude(pk__in=...)`),

Comment: Thanks @ignacio-vazquez-abrams, but how would I know if the record to be removed is in either edges of the queryset?

Comment: their is no problems to exclude ids that aren't on the queryset